# How to modify the function `as.POSIXct` to specify the time intervals to be plotted in R basic plot()?

Tags: r, datetime, time-series

I am not comfortable working with time formats, and specifically, `as.POSIXct` within the basic R `plot()` function to establish the labels of the x-axis. You can run the entire code below, but the difficulty lies in modifying

```
axis.POSIXct(1,NY$date, at=NY$date,
             labels=format(NY$date,"%m-%d"),
             las=2, cex.axis=0.7)
```

I have tried changing that to

```
axis.POSIXct(1,NY$date, at=NY$date, by = 4,
             labels=format(NY$date,"%m-%d"),
             las=2, cex.axis=0.7)
```

intending 4 days, but I think it ended up interpreted as every 4 seconds. I saw there was an option of including `'days'` but I really would like to specify **every 4 days**.

Splitting the code for the axis into an `at` line resulted in mismatches in lengths, rendering the code useless. For instance:

```
at <- seq(NY$date[2], NY$date[length(NY$date], by=2)
```

ENTIRE CODE CHUNK:

```
require(tidyverse) 
states = read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-states.csv", sep =",",header = T)
states <- states %>%
      mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date, format = '%Y-%m-%d'))
    
# Tri-state cases (NY, NJ, PA):

NJ <- states[states$state=="New Jersey",]
NJ <- droplevels(NJ)
rownames(NJ) <- NULL

NY <- states[states$state=="New York",]
NY <- droplevels(NY)
rownames(NY) <- NULL

PA <- states[states$state=="Pennsylvania",]
PA <- droplevels(PA)
rownames(PA) <- NULL

with(as.data.frame(NY),
     plot(date,cases,xaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="", pch=19, 
          cex.axis=0.6, cex=0.7,
          cex.main=1.5, las=2, bty='l',
          main="Tri-state confirmed cases"))
axis.POSIXct(1,NY$date, at=NY$date,
             labels=format(NY$date,"%m-%d"),
             las=2, cex.axis=0.7)
points(NJ$date, NJ$cases, pch=19, col=4, cex=0.7)
points(PA$date, PA$cases, pch=19, col=5, cex=0.7)

legend(NY$date[1], 300000, bg="transparent",
       legend=c("New York state", "New Jersey", "Pennsylvania"),
       col=c(1, 4, 5), pch=19, cex=1.2, box.lty=0)
```

Comment: There is no `by` parameter in `axis.POSIXct`

Comment: Do you want to generate a sequence first, and then use that in your axis labels? E.g.: `ats <- seq(trunc(min(NY$date), "days"), trunc(max(NY$date), "days"), by="4 days");
axis.POSIXct(1, ats, at=ats,
             labels=format(ats, "%m-%d"),
             las=2, cex.axis=0.7)`

Comment: @thelatemail That works, thank you. Ideally, I wish I could extend the dates by a few dates at the tails.I wonder what `trunc` does, and why `ats` has to be entered twice in `axis.POSIXct`.